# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("studid",typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("rollno", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt1.Columns.Add("starttime", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("class", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("section", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("subject", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {               
                dt1.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["id"]), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["rollno"]), Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text),time.SelectedItem.ToString(), drpclass.SelectedItem.ToString(), drpsection.ToString(), drpsubject.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }
```

I am getting error `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"` at `time.SelectedItem.ToString()` even though the datatype of DataTable's column is string.
I applied breakpoint and `09:30:00` is the value i am getting in `time.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Comment: It's more likely that Convert.ToDateTime throws the exception.

Comment: I would avoid such one-liners. Use variables in the for-loop, that'll make the code more readable and it simplifies debugging.

Comment: I am getting error at 
time.SelectedItem.ToString()

Comment: @Arbaaz: How do you know that you're gettting the error there if you get _"9:30:00 for time.SelectedItem.ToString"_?

Comment: And how do you know you get the error there, when it's all in one line? Break out each value to separate variables, performing the parsing and assigning on seven separate lines. THEN add them to the row.

Comment: You people are right its Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text) which is throwing error. The exception was pointing towards time so i thought i have problem there. How do i solve it?

Comment: I am using calendar to pick date for that textbox and "3/15/2013" is the value of txtdate.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what value you have in this field `txtdate.Text` May be it's causing a problem.

You are doing this

```
 Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text)
```

So if TextBox contains different value other than date format. then It will throw an error.

Comment: "3/15/2013" is the value id txtdate.Text and yes this is the culprit. How do i solve this? I am using Calendar to select date in that textbox

Answer (score 3):

Your input '09:30:00' mentions only the time while your datatype for the corresponding column is DateTime of which the input includes the Day,Month and Year.

(Assuming that it is a drop down list)
So,in order to get the Time in string do the following:

```
string mytime=  DateTime.Parse(DropDownlist.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()).ToShortTimeString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to indicate an issue with converting a `string` value to a `Datetime`.

The only place that this conversion takes place is the

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text)
```

line.  Can you double check the value of `txtdate` and ensure that it is a valid date.

Comment: "3/15/2013" is the value id txtdate.Text and yes this is the culprit. How do i solve this? I am using Calendar to select date in that textbox

Comment: @Arbaaz by default the conversion format is american, which equates to dd/mm/yyyy. As 15 is invalid for month, it errors.  Either change the calendar control to output the date in the American format or include the `IFormatProvider` in the conversion function - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t.aspx for more info on this. eg, `Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text, new CultureInfo("en-gb"))`.